# DataTables sorting icons don't show up without minified CSS

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I came across something that I thought was very strange while installing the dataTables plugin in my app.  I am using ruby on rails 4.2.

If i have only the minified or only the non-minified js and css `jquery.dataTables` files in my assets, the sorting icons do not load properly.
I get a `RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/sort_desc.png")`.  I've seen other people discuss this error, but have not actually seen a good solution for it. 
If I change the path to retrieve the images inside `jquery.dataTables.css` or the min version of the file, I still get the same error.  The path in the error message does not change!

The strange thing, is if I use the min.css and regular js files, the sorting icons load properly!
Recap:
`jquery.dataTables.min.css` & `jquery.dataTables.js`  : WORKS

`jquery.dataTables.css` & `jquery.dataTables.js`  : DOES NOT WORK

`jquery.dataTables.min.css` & `jquery.dataTables.min.js`  : DOES NOT WORK

`jquery.dataTables.css` & `jquery.dataTables.min.js`  : DOES NOT WORK

I am putting these files inside `vendor/assets/stylesheets`, `../javascripts`, `../images`.
What is going on here?

Comment: Are you running this in production mode? if so, make sure you precompile your assets.

Comment: I am just running this in development currently.  Also, rails adds files in all directories under vendor/assets by default.  If I run `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` in the console, I can see `/vendor/assets/images`, `/vendor/assets/stylesheets`, and `/vendor/assets/javascripts` are being added.

Comment: try `image_tag("sort_desc.png")` in a view. (usually in DEV the assets are located at `/assets/image.png`, `/assets/javascript.js` etc.

Comment: `jquery.datatTables.min.js` is a copy pasta typo, yeah? I assume that's not from your actual code.

Comment: @RaVeN That image tag path does work if I use it any view.  However, changing the path in the `jquery.dataTables.css` or min version has no effect.  Rails still reports the error I mentioned above and is looking for it in "/images/sort_desc.png".  Not sure why

Comment: @MarsAtomic `jquery.dataTables.min.js` is the file name and full extension.  When I require it, I use `//= require jquery.dataTables.min`
EDIT:  Oh, I see the typo now.  Yeah, that was just a copy paste typo, its not like that in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.  You need to override urls used in `jquery.dataTables.css`.  I create a new css file also inside the vendor/assets/stylesheets and entered the following:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting {
  background-image: image-url("sort_both.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc {
  background-image: image-url("sort_asc.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
  background-image: image-url("sort_desc.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled {
  background-image: image-url("sort_asc_disabled.png");
}
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled {
  background-image: image-url("sort_desc_disabled.png");
}
```

This works assuming you placed your images in vendor/assets/images and you also import your css override file after the datatables css is imported.